# Exclude products from Related Product display in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to exclude specific products from displaying on WooCommerce Single Product 'Related Product' section. I tried to use the filters available in includes/wc-templates/functions.php but no luck. Here is my current code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'jk_related_products_args' );
function jk_related_products_args( $args ) {
    $args['exclude'] = array('2215, 2208, 1965, 1630'); // exclude products in ALGORDANZA Family Diamonds category
    return $args;
}
```

I already tried this method I found here: [Exclude related products ids in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340067/exclude-related-products-ids-in-woocommerce) but it donsn't work either. I'm using WooCommerce Version 3.5.1

Comment: Sorry but [Exclude related products ids in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340067/exclude-related-products-ids-in-woocommerce) still perfectly works in Woocommerce 3.5.2 … the problem is in `array('2215, 2208, 1965, 1630')` that should be instead `array('2215', '2208', '1965', '1630')`… So next time check your code before saying that an answer doesn't work please.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Sorry, I missed the quotation on the array. Thank you for your help!