# Exclude a product category from Woocommerce related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In woocommerce, I am trying to remove a specific product category from displayed related products on single product pages.

I have tried to use a function hooked in `woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms`, filter hook, like in [some answer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms), but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

How to exclude a specific product category from Woocommerce related products?

Comment: Check if this simple [woocommerce related products](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wt-woocommerce-related-products/) plugin helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `woocommerce_related_products` hook in the following hooked function, to exclude a specific product category from displayed related products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'exclude_product_category_from_related_products', 10, 3 );
function exclude_product_category_from_related_products( $related_posts, $product_id, $args  ){
    // HERE define your product category slug
    $term_slug = 'hoodies';

    // Get the product Ids in the defined product category
    $exclude_ids = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'    => 'publish',
        'limit'     => -1,
        'category'  => array($term_slug),
        'return'    => 'ids',
    ) );

    return array_diff( $related_posts, $exclude_ids );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Related answer thread: [Exclude related products ids in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340067/exclude-related-products-ids-in-woocommerce/50345889#50345889)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I added the code to my site but it show critical error.